# Getting indices of 1's in a byte array

Tags: java

Given the byte array:

```
{255, 3, 5}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
{11111111, 00000011, 00000101}
```

I'd like to get the following result:

```
{23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16, 9,8, 2,0}
```

Which is an array of the indices of 1's in the input array.

What's the fastest way of doing this in Java?

**Update:**
I've chosen the fastest solution, which @aioobe's. Here are the test results of a pretty big data test:

@aioobe's way:

```
35s 289ms
35s 991ms
36s 174ms
```

@Martijn's way:

```
39s 274ms
39s 879ms
38s 684ms
```

Thanks you all! I appreciate your help.

Comment: Can the array be of arbitrary length, or is it always 3 bytes long?

Comment: It's of an arbitrary length. The maximum index can be specified by (numOfBytes * 8) - 1. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the fastest way of doing this in Java?

Presumably by a 256 entry look-up table of the type `int[][]` in which `lut[yourByte]` equals the array of indexes for the ones in `yourByte`.

You then just do something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
    for (int indexes : lut[bytes[i]])
        appendToResult(indexes + (bytes.length - 1 - i) * 8);
```

Comment: Thanks @aioobe, unfortunately I have no idea how to work with lookup tables .. I'll try to see how they work and how I can use them and test the speed of your code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

**Tested code (http://ideone.com/7NUjY):**

```
public static List<Integer> getBitsIndices(byte[] input, boolean b)
{
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; ++i)
    {
        byte j = input[i];
        for (int k = 7, bit = 1 << 7; k >= 0; --k, bit >>>= 1)
        {
            if ((j & bit) == bit == b)
            {
                list.add((input.length - i) * 8 - (8 - k));
            }
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Use it this way:

```
byte[] input = {(byte) 255, (byte) 3, (byte) 5};
System.out.println(getBitsIndices(input, true));
```

Output:

```
[23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 9, 8, 2, 0]
```

Comment: That's awesome @Martijn, would you mind giving me code to reverse the operation? i.e. to get the original byte array from the list? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would (given {255, 3, 5} in integer) and always the last bit with 0x1 and then shift to the right.
Both operations are fast and have native CPU support.

Example:

```
pos, index = 0; res[];
00000101 AND 0x1 -> TRUE; res[index++] = pos++;
shift right
00000010 AND 0x1 -> FALSE; pos++;
shift right
```

... and so on.

I will make a test implementation this evening.

Comment: Thanks @pewpew, the problem is I'm really bad at the bits level, and I can hardly understand their operations. I would really appreciate the full code snippet. Thanks!